# Coloured tail with geom_histogram without a step

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution

There is a distribution and I like to colour the long tail from a specific value up to the end.
When I use geom_histogram and *aes(fill)* with a 0-1-varibale I get a step.

Any Ideas how to prevent this?

Example:

```
set.seed(2713)
df <- data.frame(var_a = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 10, sd = 2))
df2 <- data.frame(x = 12, y = 13)

ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = df, aes(var_a, fill = var_a > 12)) +
  geom_point(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y), shape = 1, size = 15)
```

[image: Histogram with coloured tail and step]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the same logic after the statistic part of the layer has binned the data with `after_stat()`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2713)
df <- data.frame(var_a = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 10, sd = 2))
df2 <- data.frame(x = 12, y = 13)

ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(data = df, 
                 aes(var_a, fill = after_stat(x > 12)))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know the function _after_stat()_.
What does it mean to use **x** instead of **var_a** ?

Comment: Internally, ggplot2 converts `var_a` to a column named 'x' to store that data during the plot building process. `after_stat()` doesn't 'see' the original data (the `var_a` column), but it does 'see' evaluated statistics (the `x` column).